# Links to pages except current domain

Tags: php, static-linking

As the title says I have an array with all the domains of my site for different countries.
What I want is to loop this array and echo it to browser but I don't want to include the current domain to the list.

Example: `domains = ['test1.com', 'test2.pl','test3.it','test4.uk','test5.de']`

I want my foreach loop print all the above domains except the one that the user currently visits, so if  you visit test1.com page, all the other pages should be listed.
I'm using a php framework but probably it's irrelevant.

This is my current code:

```
@foreach(sites as $site)
<a class="" href="http://{{ $site }}">{{ $site }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try feeding $site through [parse_url](http://php.net/parse_url). You can than extract the hostname and match it against the currently requested hostname (via the $_SERVER variable)

Comment: thanks! It works fine. And especially for laravel you can use this: 'substr (Request::root(), 7);'

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` This gets the current URI.

You would only need to include a if to check if sites == `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

For more info about the server array see this php manual link: [Click me](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)